# Notepad++ regex string to string that repeats

Tags: notepad++, regex

Can someone help me create a regex that works in notepad++ for this situation?

Let's say I have this text:

```
111111
something something text    
222222    
something something text
something something text    
111111    
something something text
something something text
something something text    
222222   
something something text
something something text    
something something text
something something text   
111111   
something something text    
222222
```

I want to choose the Strings that are in between 111111 and 222222 including 111111 and 222222.

I have tried `(111111)*(222222)` but in only chooses 222222. I have also tried `(111111).*(222222)` but it chooses everything in the text. So, how do I get the first 111111 to 222222 set of string?

Comment: Try `(111111).*?(222222)` or just `111111.*?222222`

Comment: It can't find anything :(

Comment: It works for me. Did you click on `. matches newline`?

Comment: @SpiderPig: Put it as an answer, this is the solution.

Comment: I did check both of those but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

the regex `111111.*?222222` will do what you want but you have to make sure that `Regular Expression` and `. matches newline` are both checked.
The question mark makes the regex "lazy" as explained in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_matching). This means that it will match as little as possible instead of the entire text.